# Get name of constant by value

Tags: c#

I have a class with constants. I have some string, which can be same as name of one of that constants or not.

So class with constants ConstClass has some public const like const1, const2, const3...

```
public static class ConstClass
{
    public const string Const1 = "const1";
    public const string Const2 = "const2";
    public const string Const3 = "const3";
}
```

is it possible to get contant by value?

So "const1" value has name "Const1"

I know how to get the oposite way ...

```
string customStr = "const1";
if ((typeof (ConstClass)).GetField(customStr) != null)
{
    string value = (string)typeof(ConstClass).GetField(customStr).GetValue(null);
}
```

Comment: What if two constants share the same value? This seems like a very peculiar thing to do. Even the other way round is odd, better to have a dictionary than a bunch of constants you look up via reflection.

Comment: Why not just use an enum...

Comment: @DavidG although what you explained is clearly a better option. but have you considered the OP point of view?

Comment: @Valkyrie What point of view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple solution.

Example:

```
public static class Names
{
   public const string name1 = "Name 01";
   public const string name2 = "Name 02";

   public static string GetNames(string code)
   {
      foreach (var field in typeof(Names).GetFields())
      {
         if ((string)field.GetValue(null) == code)
         return field.Name.ToString();
      }
      return "";
   }
}
```

and following will print "name1"

```
string result = Names.GetNames("Name 01");
Console.WriteLine(result )
```

Comment: But what if we have two constants with the same value in the same class?

Comment: This example does not work if there are other fields than constants in your class. You need at least `GetFields(BindingFlags.Static)` otherwise it fails.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first of all you have to understand what problem you are really solving. If you need to have generic method to all possible classes and you have no duplicated values so you can use code below:

```
public string GetConstNameByValue<T>(string constValue) =>
           typeof(T)
                // Gets all public and static fields
                .GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                // IsLiteral determines if its value is written at 
                //   compile time and not changeable
                // IsInitOnly determine if the field can be set 
                //   in the body of the constructor
                // for C# a field which is readonly keyword would have both true 
                //   but a const field would have only IsLiteral equal to true
                .Where(f => f.IsLiteral && !f.IsInitOnly)
                .FirstOrDefault(f => f.GetValue(null) == constValue)
                ?.Name;
```

But reflection is very slow and it's better to not use it if not needed. Also, you can't handle situations with same values of several constants.

If you have only one class with collection of constant values it's better to have a method to this class which not using reflection:

```
public string GetConstNameByValue(string constValue)
{
    if (ConstClass.Const1 == constValue)
        return nameof(ConstClass.Const1);
    if (ConstClass.Const2 == constValue)
        return nameof(ConstClass.Const2);
    if (ConstClass.Const3 == constValue)
        return nameof(ConstClass.Const3);
    throw new ArgumentException("There is no constants with expectedValue", nameof(constValue));
}
```

Comment: This is awful though, see my comment above.

Comment: Also very slow as it needs to get the value of every single constant.

Comment: @DavidG I agree with you, the solution depends entirely on the original problem. My code illustrates the closest solution to the original problem, but may not be appropriate due to context. I'll fix my answer with details.

Answer (score 1):

you can try reflection:

```
var expextedValue = "const1";
var props = typeof(ConstClass).GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static);
var wantedProp = props.FirstOrDefault(prop => (string)prop.GetValue(null) == expextedValue );
```